# Every group of totally disconnected type is locally profinite?

Tags: topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a Hausdorff topological group in which every point has a neighborhood basis of open compact neighborhoods.  Let's call this a group of totally disconnected (td)-type.

On the other hand, we have a notion of a *locally profinite group*, a Hausdorff topological group which has a neighborhood basis of the identity consisting of open compact subgroups.  A locally profinite group is obviously of td-tytpe.

Is there an example of a group of td-type which is not locally profinite?

Answer (score 7):

"Is there an example of a group of td-type which is not locally profinite?"

No.  This was proved by D. van Dantzig in the 1930s:

Van Dantzig, D.: Zur topologischen Algebra. III. Brouwersche und Cantorsche Gruppen, Compositio Mathematica, Volume 3 (1936), p. 408-426

For a modern presentation of the proof, see e.g. Phillip Wesolek's lecture notes:
http://people.math.binghamton.edu/wesolek/tdlc_Polish_groups/tdlcPolish.html